# How can I programmatically find the path of JNLP file? I am using Java Web Start to generate the JNLP file

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

How can I programmatically find the path of JNLP file?I am using Java Web Start to generate the JNLP file.
I know that manually you can find the JNLP file in the Java Cache Viewer in Resources with the name `launch.jnlp`, but I really need to know if there exists a Java class that can programmatically find the jnlp file by searching the in-memory cache.

Comment: A better question is - What feature are you trying to implement?  Whatever that feature is, you are going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I programatically find the path of JNLP file?

It is hidden deliberately.  If you can find it from within code (shorting of asking the user to browse to it), the JRE has a security bug.

> ..for launching the installer I need the application jar files path

No you don't.

- Put the installer inside a Jar.
- Add the Jar to the resources of the app.
- Get an URL using `getResource(String)`.
- Read the `byte[]` and write it to a temporary *file at a **known** location* (e.g. `java.io.tmpdir`).
- Launch the installer from the known location.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer.My problem is that in Java 7 Update 6, getCacheEntry() method was remove without any explanations and i don't know another way to obtain the application jar files path from memory cache, so i thought i should look for a way to obtain the jnlp file path, but if JRE has a security bug that's not possible. What do you advice me to do in this situation?

Comment: Before we proceed, I need an answer to (a little louder this time) ***What feature are you trying to implement?***  Explain it to me as you might explain it to an end user, to convince me this is 'must have' functionality so I buy the software.

Comment: I am using java web start for obtaining the installer of my application, and for launching the installer i need the application jar files path that i obtained them from memory cache with getCachedFiles() method(available in Java 7 Update 5).

Comment: And i forget to say that it's obligatory to use java web start for the installer(client specific demand) and another solution would be to include the luncher in autostart, but  i don't know how.

Comment: When I wrote the update I was presuming JWS was invoking all that from an `installer-desc` JNLP extension!  I do not understand how the 'other solution' solves anything.  What do you mean by 'autostart'?

Comment: Sorry i ment auto-install and i don't know exactly what that means i only read in a forum that it could be a solution to use it.

Answer (score 0):

String jnlpPath = System.getProperty("jnlpx.origFilenameArg");